# How to calculate the highest income in the particular year?

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to calculate highest income among the variable Index for each year.
my data frame below :

`head(data)`

```
 Index      State   Y2002   Y2003   Y2004   Y2005   Y2006   Y2007   Y2008   Y2009
1     A    Alabama 1296530 1317711 1118631 1492583 1107408 1440134 1945229 1944173
2     A     Alaska 1170302 1960378 1818085 1447852 1861639 1465841 1551826 1436541
3     A    Arizona 1742027 1968140 1377583 1782199 1102568 1109382 1752886 1554330
4     A   Arkansas 1485531 1994927 1119299 1947979 1669191 1801213 1188104 1628980
5     C California 1685349 1675807 1889570 1480280 1735069 1812546 1487315 1663809
6     C   Colorado 1343824 1878473 1886149 1236697 1871471 1814218 1875146 1752387
    Y2010   Y2011   Y2012   Y2013   Y2014   Y2015
1 1237582 1440756 1186741 1852841 1558906 1916661
2 1629616 1230866 1512804 1985302 1580394 1979143
3 1300521 1130709 1907284 1363279 1525866 1647724
4 1669295 1928238 1216675 1591896 1360959 1329341
5 1624509 1639670 1921845 1156536 1388461 1644607
6 1913275 1665877 1491604 1178355 1383978 1330736
```

Comment: can u please be more specific?

Comment: for each year i want to calculate the highest income

Comment: any sample code tried ?

Comment: data%>%select(Index,-State,everything())%>%group_by(.)...after this i dont know how to filter

Comment: What variables do you want to use? Maximum by index and state, too? Also, could you provide data in an easy-to-paste form? See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
colMax <- function(data) sapply(data, max, na.rm = TRUE)
colMax(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

Find 2 possible solutions using `dplyr` (and `tidyr` for the first solution) below:

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
df <- read.table(text = " Index      State   Y2002   Y2003   Y2004   Y2005   Y2006   Y2007   Y2008   Y2009
1     A    Alabama 1296530 1317711 1118631 1492583 1107408 1440134 1945229 1944173
           2     A     Alaska 1170302 1960378 1818085 1447852 1861639 1465841 1551826 1436541
           3     A    Arizona 1742027 1968140 1377583 1782199 1102568 1109382 1752886 1554330
           4     A   Arkansas 1485531 1994927 1119299 1947979 1669191 1801213 1188104 1628980
           5     C California 1685349 1675807 1889570 1480280 1735069 1812546 1487315 1663809
           6     C   Colorado 1343824 1878473 1886149 1236697 1871471 1814218 1875146 1752387
           ", header = T)

# if you want to use group_by, as in your comment,
# then you need to transform data to long first, then calculate, then
# optionally go back to wide:
df %>% 
  gather(key = year, value = value, matches("\\d{4}$")) %>% 
  group_by(year) %>% 
  summarise(value_max = max(value)) %>% 
  spread(year, value_max)

# if you want to avoid that tranformation, you could use mutate_at:
df %>% 
  summarise_at(.vars = vars(matches("\\d{4}$")), max)
```